# Why does this simple drag and drop code cause the element to flicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousemove

I've got some very simple drag and drop jQuery code for vertical drag and drop:

```
function drag(ele){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        yPos = ele.offset();
        yPos = yPos.top;
        diff = (yPos + ele.height()) - e.pageY;
        ele.css('top', e.pageY - diff);
    }).mouseup(function(){
        $(this).unbind('mousemove');
    });
}
```

It works perfectly well, except sometimes it starts flickering through small changes and the diff variable jumps around. I have no idea what may be causing this, perhaps someone else does?

http://jsfiddle.net/GTGMN/2/

The problem is much more prominent in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're changing the `top` property on the element and at the same time you're using that info to move the element. Try this for example:

```
function drag(ele){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        ele.css('top', e.pageY);
    }).mouseup(function(){
        $(this).unbind('mousemove');
    });
}

$('.box').mousedown(function(){
    drag($(this));
})
```

This code will put the element directly where the cursor is. It might not be exactly what you want, but try to move the element without depending directly on its previous position.

**Update:**

The question asked for a 1-1 movement where the click started. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utVXU/) does that. The idea is to calculate the difference from the click position to the top of the box when the dragging begins, and then update the position using that offset.

Comment: This works fine, I was aiming for a perfect 1:1 drag and drop but I guess it's more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Your math seems very strange. What exactly is the point of the `diff` variable?

Don't you just want: ?

```
ele.css('top', e.pageY);
```

or

```
ele.css('top', e.pageY - ele.height() / 2);
```

Comment: I wanted a perfect, 1:1 drag and drop. Just being a perfectionist, I guess it's simpler to resort to your suggestion.